# Campo file en registercontroller laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Buen día, tengo este dilema, tengo un campo file en el formulario register de laravel, hice mas grande la tabla users por conveniencia, los campos me los guarda bien y todo, pero no puedo manejar la imagen como la manejo en los otros formularios, quisiera que me ayudaran con esto.

Gracias.

adjunto el formulario:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'telefono' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:99999999', 'min:00000000'],
            'direccion' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'sueldo' => ['numeric','min:0.01','max:0.99'],
            'foto' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
        if ($data['foto']->hasFile('foto')){
            $file = $data['foto']->file('foto');
            $data['nom_imagen'] = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/imagenes/',$data['nom_imagen']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'direccion' => $data['direccion'],
            'sueldo' => $data['sueldo'],
            'foto' => $data['nom_imagen'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu método "validator" nunca llegarás a guardar el archivo ya que apenas entra pones un "return".

Comment: entonces como debería de ir?